# Javascript close event

Tags: javascript, events

I want to allow this event to happen only when the button is enabled and only if i close the browser, not when i click the button( as the unload event is triggerd even then).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var allowPrompt = false;
            function enableSaveButton() {
                //alert("yes");
                var Btn = document.getElementById("ButtonSave");
                Btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
               allowPrompt = true;
            }
            function areYouSure() {
                if (allowPrompt) {
                        var confMessage = "***************************************\n\n Before leaving the Budget page, please check that everything is saved.\n\n***************************************";
                        return confMessage;
                } 
            }
            var Btn = document.getElementById("ButtonSave");
                window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the button is enabled on function areYouSure or put this window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure; on enableSaveButton function, i guess.

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem where it detects the close function as the same as anything else that triggers the unload.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body div or the parent div that you are unloading so the function will get called correctly

```
 <body onbeforeunload="areYouSure()">
```

Comment: There is no problem calling the function.